# Python : How to bring value from one dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob','Bob','Bob'],'income':[400,500, 420],'expenses':[400,2500,420]})
df1.user.unique()

return_val = df[(df['Payer']=='Bob')]
```

I have two dataframes (df and df1) and I do not want to hard code 'Bob' in return_val. Is there anyway through which I can get 'Bob' by reading df1 ? Am trying something like this which seems incomplete.

```
return_val = df[(df['Payer']== df1.user.unique())]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There's no `mapping` in your question.

Comment: could you show an example of `df` or your expected output?

Comment: I edited my question. In 'return_val' I want to bring 'Bob' from df1 without hard coding df['Payer']=='Bob'. 'Bob' should read from df1.

Comment: I think the problem remains unclear

Comment: `return_val = df[(df['Payer']==df1.user.unique()[0])]` or `return_val = df[(df['Payer']==df1['user'].iat[0])]` , however the question is unclear as mentioned

Comment: Sounds like an inner join to me

Comment: use `df.loc[df['Payer'].isin(df1['user'])]` or ...`df.merge(df1[['user']],left_on = 'Payer', right_on ='user', how ='right').loc[:,df.columns]`

Comment: @anky_91I was missing [0] in unique() and thats why giving unusual results. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
mask=df1['user'].unique()[0]
return_val = df[mask]
```

but it work only if you have 'Bob' only in the  'user' column

Comment: Yes. there is only 'Bob' in the column. There are multiple files having different user names.